# Adding field to multiple shapefiles including their designated filepaths as values using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I am trying to create a script that navigates a directory and adds a field to a shapefile called "filepath" and then paste the file path in the rows of that parcticular shapefile. This is the code that I am working on below

```
enter code here
for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(dest):
    for f in f_names:

        if f.endswith('.shp'):
            src = os.path.join(root,f)
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(path + f, f, "ogr")
            processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', {layer, 'Filepath' , 2 , 150 ,0 , True, src, src})
```

This is the current error that I get:

> TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.parameterAsBool(): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'set'

I'm using QGIS 3.4